# JQuery sliders / Carousels - Jagged fonts in Chrome (Windows) - bxslider and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, webfonts, bxslider

So I've made a carousel... I've tried it using bootstrap carousel and also bxSlider.

I'm using brandon grotesque via typekit.

The font looks great on mac and even on all windows browsers apart from Chrome.

On chrome the anti aliasing is horrible and very bitty / jagged.

I've read quite a lot of articles which suggest font-smoothing, translateZ, backface etc but nothing seems to work. Could anyone help with this please :) ?

http://brandoning.com/slider/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I ended up getting rid of any occurrence of "Webkit" in the jquery.bxslider.js file. Mine works and there has been no repercussions in doing so (at least from what I've seen).

Here's what I did:
OLD (line 159): var props = ['WebkitPerspective', 'MozPerspective', 'OPerspective', 'msPerspective'];
NEW: var props = ['MozPerspective', 'OPerspective', 'msPerspective'];

OLD (line 546): el.bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){
NEW: el.bind('transitionend oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){

OLD (line 548): el.unbind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd');
NEW: el.unbind('transitionend oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd');

OLD (line 558): el.bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){
NEW: el.bind('transitionend oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){

OLD (line 560): el.unbind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd');
NEW: el.unbind('transitionend oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd');